# UINavigationItem backBarButtonItem issue during screen transition

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I have UINavigationController with 2 view controllers `vc1` and `vc2` (`vc1` pushes `vc2`). I need to set back button title of `vc2`, so I do it by:

```
vc1.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem 
       = UIBarButtonItem(title: title, style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

But this `back button title` is a counter, I get it from Database, so I usually set it after `viewWillAppear` but before `viewDidAppear` (it happens during navigation controller transition from `vc1` to `vc2`)

But the `back button title` is applied only after the transition is completed. As a comparison if I use `leftBarButtonItem` with `custom view`, the title is applied before the transition is completed. But I'm not allowed to use `leftBarButtonItem`

Here is the [Video](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/69908583ce6494143ce98ab383c0d57e20200130131230/288e97) how it looks like (it's possible to notice if you scroll video slowly)

Is it possible somehow to force update back button title before the transition is completed?

Comment: Have you tried applying it when you init vc2?

Comment: it's too early to apply it on init (cause there is no id to extract from DB, but I tried applying it on viewDidLoad - didn't help, I anyway get a counter between viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear